# if I call a php file from another php file loaded with ajax I get error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Like the title says, I'm doing an ajax call to a php file like this:

```
function loadForm(val1, val2, val3){
    $.ajax({

        url : 'AL_loadForm.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : {
            value1 :val1,
            value2: val2,
            value3:val3
        },
        dataType:'json',
        success : function(data) {              
            alert(data);
        },
        error : function(request,error)
        {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

And in my loadForm.php I've got two cases, If I load this code I got a successful ajax call without error:

```
<?php 
if($_POST){


    $var1 = $_POST['value1'];
    $var2 = $_POST['value2'];
    $var3 = $_POST['value3'];
    echo json_encode($var1);
}
?>
```

But if I load this same code with an include php file I get an error in my ajax call

```
 <?php 
    if($_POST){

        include 'AL_createTbObj.php';
        $var1 = $_POST['value1'];
        $var2 = $_POST['value2'];
        $var3 = $_POST['value3'];
        echo json_encode($var1);
    }
```

Is this normal? can't do stuff in another php files with a single ajax call??

EDIT: to add content of AL_createTBObj.php,
basically it creates an object from the class tableRows.php

```
<?php
     require 'tableRows.php';

        //Create mySqli object with DB Params
        $conn = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbDB);
        //Create TableRows object
        $tb = new TableRows($conn);
        //Connect to Data Base
        $tb->checkDb();
?>
```

There is some `echo 'content'`.. in the class tableRows.php but those methods aren't called yet....

Comment: What error in your ajax call

Comment: What's in `AL_createTbObj.php`?

Comment: The same call prints alert(error) when I load the second php code fragment with the include line

Comment: Show us the contents of `AL_createTbObj.php`, does it have any echo's in it?? That would explain the error. Or maybe it does not actually compile

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: It's a file that create an object. I edit to add this file's code

Comment: There is an echo in the tableRows.php class, but it's in a method and I haven't called it yet. This can be the reason?

Comment: Is all your variables is defined? Try execute your code with include string, but without ajax.P.S. don't forget to comment `if($_POST)` condition

Comment: I've been trying to comment every echo in the tableRows.php and finally I think I've found the reason, despite I don't understand it very well. There is some javascript code after the tableRows.php class definition and after I commented it, it works

Answer (score 0):

Your  `AL_createTBObj.php` file is missing the `<?php` at the top. This means that the contents will be returned as text instead of being handled as php.

Check this and any other included files have the `<?php` before any code - at the very top of the file if it's all php. You do not need to terminate files with the `?>` and you may choose to leave it out as this has the advantage of ensuring no whitespace at the end of the file after the `?>` is sent to the client.

Comment: Ok, use `curl -i --data "value1=1&value2=2&value3=3" https://yoursite.com/AL_loadForm.php` to simulate the request to your server and view the response from PHP. See what changes when you add the extra line of code.

Answer (score 0):

After comment a lot of line of codes I've finally figured that it was a javascript code added after the class definition that was causing the error. I still don't understand why but I think I'll add this javascript code in a separate .js file. Thanks to all the answers!

```
<?php 
class TableRows {
code...
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myCreateFunction(string,offerId,offerName,iniciadas,finalizadas,unsuccesful,successful,revenue,unsuccesfulPerCent,filtradas,trafico,traficoPerCent,biddingScore) {

    var offerId =  '<tr><th>'+offerId+'</th></tr>';
    var offerName =  '<tr><th>'+offerName+'</th></tr>';
    var iniciadas =  '<tr><th>'+iniciadas+'</th></tr>';
    var finalizadas =  '<tr><th>'+finalizadas+'</th></tr>';
    var unsuccessful =  '<tr><th>'+unsuccesful+'</th></tr>';
    var succesfull =  '<tr><th>'+successful+'</th></tr>';
    var revenue =  '<tr><th>'+revenue+'</th></tr>';
    var unsusccesspercent =  '<tr><th>'+unsuccesfulPerCent+'</th></tr>';
    var filtro =  '<tr><th>'+filtradas+'</th></tr>';
    var trafico =  '<tr><th>'+trafico+'</th></tr>';
    var traficoPerCent =  '<tr><th>'+traficoPerCent+'</th></tr>';
    var biddingScore =  '<tr><th>'+biddingScore+'</th></tr>';

    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    if(string == '1'){
        row.className = "alt";
    }else{
        row.className = "alt2";
    }


    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
    var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
    var cell8 = row.insertCell(7);
    var cell9 = row.insertCell(8);
    var cell10 = row.insertCell(9);
    var cell11 = row.insertCell(10);
    var cell12 = row.insertCell(11);         



    cell1.innerHTML = offerId;
    cell2.innerHTML = offerName;
    cell3.innerHTML = iniciadas;
    cell4.innerHTML = finalizadas;
    cell5.innerHTML = unsuccessful;
    cell6.innerHTML = succesfull;
    cell7.innerHTML = revenue;
    cell8.innerHTML = unsusccesspercent;
    cell9.innerHTML = filtro;
    cell10.innerHTML = trafico;
    cell11.innerHTML = traficoPerCent;
    cell12.innerHTML = biddingScore;


}
</script>
```

I have commented all the javascript code and now ajax do a success call!